# How to stop backgroundworker

Tags: c#, winforms

Almost all the example of backgroundworker consists of for loop. But my requirement do not need any loop. I have following code running i backgroundworker. How do i cancel the worker process without using the for loop

```
 void form_DoWork(LoadingProgress sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

            //for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        //{


        //    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
        //    sender.SetProgress(i, "Step " + i.ToString() + " / 100...");
        //    if (sender.CancellationPending)
        //    {
        //        e.Cancel = true;
        //        return;
        //    }
        //}
              // heavy database process       
             SomeClass.BulkInsert(ExportLine);
        }  


   private void ButtonCancelClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //notify the background worker we want to cancel
        worker.CancelAsync();
      //disable the cancel button and change the status text
        buttonCancel.Enabled = false;
        labelStatus.Text = CancellingText;
    }
```

Comment: You can't, at least no easily.  Since BulkInsert provides no way to cancel the operation, there's little you can do short of aborting the thread, and that's just really messy.

Comment: Any alternative to show progress work for time consuming processing

Comment: Is **SomeClass** a black box for you?

Comment: If this is an heavy database process you can wrap it up in a transaction and vote for rolling it back if and when you cancel.

Comment: @arjun - No.  There is no alternative, you can't do it.  Your BulkInsert object provides no way to cancel or discover progress.  If you couldn't do it in a foreground thread, you can't do it in a background thread either.  How exactly do you plan to discover this progress from something that doesn't provide it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use BackgroundWorker if that's what you need to do. Since your class doesn't provide any way to provide progress updates, the only thing it's giving you is marshalling the `RunWorkerCompleted` method.

Create a [Thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx) class, keep a reference to it and abort if you need to. Just make sure that when your background work is finished, you call Invoke if you update any controls with the results.

EDIT:

Here's a primitive example of how it could work. (note: this may not compile, i didn't write it in the IDE).

```
Thread _dbThread;

void DoLongRunningQueryAsync()
    {
        bool dbWorkFinished = false;
        _dbThread = new Thread(() =>
        {
             // heavy database process       
             SomeClass.BulkInsert(ExportLine);
             dbWorkFinished = true;
        });
        Thread monitorThread = new Thread(() =>
        {
             Thread.Sleep(5000);
             if (!dbWorkFinished)
             {
                 //Db work took too long. Abort
                 _dbThread.Abort();
                 this.Invoke(() => MessageBox.Show("Db work took too long. Query aborted"); );
             }
        });
        _dbThread.Start();
        monitorThread.Start();
     }  


   private void ButtonCancelClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _dbThread.Abort()
    }
```

Comment: Could you please show me how to do it with reference to above code.I need the cancel button as well to cancel abort the process.